# Bigcommerce uploading theme error

Tags: themes, customization, bigcommerce

I downloaded the current theme, unzipped it, put some custom html, then zipped it, then reuploaded it. The uploading is successful however the processing failed. It showed a message:

> There was a problem processing your theme

I tried renaming it and removing the html I inserted but it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Stencil theme, you will need to bundle it with Stencil CLI before uploading: 
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/bundling-submitting

If you are using a Blueprint theme, it should be uploaded to the template folder in WebDAV as described in this article: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Transferring-a-Custom-Theme-from-One-Bigcommerce-Store-to-Another

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue last night. What resolved it was making sure none of my config.json strings were over the 64 letter limit for URLs. Once I removed these, my theme was able to be uploaded successfully.

UPDATE:

The urls that affected my bundle were located in the 'settings' section of my config.json. Don't worry about the meta section (your 'documentation_url' can be left how it is). I began getting the error after building out my schema.json file. After I connected my ID's in my schema.json file to the correlating ID's in my config.json file I started getting errors. I tracked down the ID that was causing the problem and it happened to have a string that was over 64 characters long. Once I removed the string my errors went away and the theme uploaded correctly.

Comment: Hi. Could you elaborate more? Maybe send a screenshot through chrome extension? I dont know if I understand it correctly. Should I just change all URL (documentation_url) to be less than 64 characters?